# unable to run hello world program in c# console application

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and running hello world program for console application. When i'm running using f5, the console is popping up and immediately disappearing.

```
    using System;

namespace CSharpConsoleApps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello c sharp world ");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the message it's showing in output

```
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\skumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSharpConsoleApps\CSharpConsoleApps\bin\Debug\CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x12b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x674) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\skumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSharpConsoleApps\CSharpConsoleApps\bin\Debug\CSharpConsoleApps.exe', Symbols loaded.
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0xdd8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1424) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4320] CSharpConsoleApps.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your program executes successfully, but the console closes rightaway.

To prevent that, use `Ctrl+F5` instead of just `F5`.

Answer (score 6):

That is working exactly as you have told it!

Basically, that code just says 'show this line of text'. So once that is done, with nothing else to do, it stops running.

Try adding

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

And run it again

Answer (score 1):

Computers do *exactly* what they are programmed to do. That being the case, the original code did not direct the computer to wait for input from the user before it terminated. So, the computer followed the instructions as they were presented, and terminated the program normally.

You could try:

```
namespace CSharpConsoleApps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello c sharp world ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And run it again. The computer will then wait for you to press ENTER before closing the console window.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Ok, so how much more detail do I need to go into to answer the question? The comment above mine answers the question of why the console window disappears, so it would be redundant to explain it again.

Comment: Oddly I can't see the review in my history so I don't if it was dispute, declined or marked as helpful. If I saw this again I'd probably not mark it as "Not an answer".